# Difference between color and effective temperature

Tags: visible-light, temperature, thermal-radiation

What is the difference between color temperature and effective temperature of a star?

I have gone through the pages at wikipedia, but I still do not understand that. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Colour temperature:-the temperature at which a black body would emit radiation of the same colour as a given object.

Comment: @AdityaGarg Why won't the effective temperature be the same as the color temperature?

Comment: I think Teff refers to the total radiative power per square unit, while Tcol refers to the spectrum emitted if the object were a perfect blackbody

Reference https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/color-temperature-and-effective-temperature-of-a-star.708815/

Comment: OK. You mean becasue the hydrogen in the stars are not blackbodies and so are discrete and probably interferes with the data collected due to some other effects?